# Calculating Average and Standard Deviation using do while loop

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program which asks the user for a series of positive values and computes the mean and standard deviation of those values having the input stop when the user enters -1. I seem to have the average part down however. I can't seem to get the standard deviation.

So far this is what I have.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW0402

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        double x;

        double sum = 0;

        double average = 0;

        double dev = 0;

        double var = 0;

        double sqrx = 0;

        int n = 0;

        do 
        { 
            System.out.println("Enter positive values, enter -1 to end");
            x = input.nextInt(); 
            if (x == -1)
            {
                break;
            }

            sum += x;
            n++;
            average = sum / n;      
            sqrx += Math.pow(x-average,2);
            var = sqrx / (n-1);
            dev = Math.sqrt(var);


        } while (x != -1);

        System.out.println("Average: " + average);
        System.out.println("Deviation: " + dev);

    }
}
```

I seem to get odd results such as decimals when simply calculating sqrx += x- average

I'm new to java and haven't leaned alternatives to this problem, I would love it if someone pointed me in the right direction on what I should do, or explain what I did wrong.

Apologies ahead of time for any novice mistakes I made.

Comment: The mistake you are making is math related, not programming related. The average of your data set changes with each new input but you calculate a new average each time and add the square of the difference to `sqrx`. This is wrong because you will be using a different value for the average each time. Move these operations to the _outside_ of the loop. In fact, you shouldn't have any calculations in your loop at all because you don't output the results. Just move all the math outside the loop and you should get the right results.

Comment: Faraz I actually can't really reference the linked answer because we haven't covered arrays yet. @Arc676  for moving the math outside where should I move it and what lines do I move because I cannot move the sum += x, without getting the wrong output for my average. Also for the original code my average is correct, so that means when you say my average changes how does that affect sqrx += Math.pow(x-average)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n = 0;
int K = 0;
double Sum = 0;
double Sum_sqr = 0;
do { 
    System.out.println("Enter positive values, enter -1 to end");
    x = input.nextInt(); 
    if (x == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    if ( n == 0 ) K = x;
    n++;
    Sum += (x - K);
    Sum_sqr += (x - K) * (x - K);
} while (x != -1);
double mean = K + Sum / n;
double varPop = (Sum_sqr - (Sum*Sum)/n) / (n);
double varSample = (Sum_sqr - (Sum*Sum)/n) / (n-1);
double devPop = Math.sqrt(varPop);
double devSample = Math.sqrt(varSample);
```

Reference [Wikipedia: Computing Shifted Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Computing_shifted_data). Also, Population or Sample, makes a difference.

Comment: The code worked and the Wiki Link is awesome, however could you explain why sum and sum_sqr remained in the loop while the mean, varpop, varsample, etc. did not?

Comment: Probably doesn't matter where they are. Left outside the loop because they only need to be calculated once. In other words, I tested it against an array, I didn't think to print out the results for each new number. Include them in the loop by all means.